# How to debug BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, debugging, learning

How do I debug BibTeX code?  I would like to know how to:

- step through execution,
- step into and out of function calls,
- set breakpoints,
- visualize the stack,
- watch the values of various variables,

et cetera.  Are there any debugging options for BibTeX, perhaps like the `unravel` package ([available on CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unravel?lang=en) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/blefloch/latex-unravel)) for LaTeX?
     The reason I'm asking such a question is because I have been going through `texdoc tamethebeast` ([Nicolas Markey's *Tame the BeaST:  The B to X of BibTeX*](http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)) for a little while now and would like to have a better understanding of what's going on in some of the examples it presents in Chapter 4, particularly some of the later ones (starting around section 20 in said chapter) since they appear to get quite complex.  There *has* to be a better way to go about inspecting how BibTeX code of the like executes and manipulates the stack than writing them out step by step in a sort of annotated textual control-flow graph in a raw text file or — I shudder to think! — getting out pencil and paper!  (This last option would be less of a problem if I had room next to the computer from which I'm typing this on the desk it's standing on, but, *still*, it seems…needlessly archaic, shall I say…?)

Comment: I suppose one could also build things up piece by piece and then have BibTeX spit out whatever it's got so far (whether that be as an actual result or as a print statement or error on the command line,) but that way also leaves something to be desired, does it not?

Comment: I guess that most people who know BibTeX are also reasonable TeX programmers, so the approach of 'Edit in `$pop`, check the values, track them on a piece of paper' is seen as pretty standard ...

Comment: Egads, that's regrettable!

Comment: BibTeX is an independent program that's over 40% the size of TeX itself. Like TeX it is written in WEB, which is Pascal plus support for TeX documentation plus some preprocessor-like features that must have seemed a good idea at the time. Like TeX it is, in most distributions, converted to unreadable C code using `web2c` (instead of to unreadable Pascal code using `tangle`). So I guess the answer is: [like TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384881/48), BibTeX can be debugged (poorly) by building it from scratch and running in a debugger. Probably would be easier to just use Biber/BibLaTeX.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are not really on-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it or maybe ask on [Software Recommendations SX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You could build your own binary of BibTeX with the `debug`, `stats`, and `trace` flags enabled, see https://github.com/texlive/texlive-source/blob/41c7068aea2af2c2684fe08c6d48722a94589e91/extra/bibtex/bibtex.web#L185-L213

Comment: @HenriMenke:  I was sort of following the example precedent set by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384871/why-doesnt-tex-have-a-proper-debugger, but that's fair enough.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think the suggestion of building with `trace` turned on may be posted as an answer, because the question is really “how can I best debug BibTeX / see what's going on”, rather than asking for a software recommendation (when we all know that no such software exists).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Therefore the question would have to be rephrased because currently it literally asks “Is there a debugger for BibTeX?” and “Such a tool should allow [...]” rather than “How to debug BibTeX?”.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  Indeed, though this seems like an area where BibTeX could improve (perhaps BibLaTeX and/or Biber, as have been suggested, do better in this area, but the styles aren't interchangeable between systems.)  By the way, are there any run-time configuration parameters of the same sort?  It would be nice if I could use the copy of BibTeX I already have installed on my system in debug mode instead of having to build a new one, but I may do it if I absolutely have to.

Comment: @HenriMenke:  Yeah, I can reword it.  Hold on just a bit…

Comment: @HenriMenke:  There you go.  I tried to be minimally invasive the requisite edit, though, so it may not change enough…?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to compile your own `bibtex` executable where you enable the `trace` flag.

From the BibTeX source code ([`bibtex.web`](https://github.com/texlive/texlive-source/blob/41c7068aea2af2c2684fe08c6d48722a94589e91/extra/bibtex/bibtex.web#L185-L213)):

> ```
> @^debugging@>
> @^statistics@>
> Some of the code below is intended to be used only when diagnosing the
> strange behavior that sometimes occurs when \BibTeX\ is being
> installed or when system wizards are fooling around with \BibTeX\
> without quite knowing what they are doing. Such code will not normally
> be compiled; it is delimited by the codewords
> `$|debug|\ldots|gubed|$', with apologies to people who wish to
> preserve the purity of English. Similarly, there is some conditional
> code delimited by `$|stat|\ldots|tats|$' that is intended only for use
> when statistics are to be kept about \BibTeX's memory/cpu usage,
> and there is conditional code delimited by `$|trace|\ldots|ecart|$'
> that is intended to be a trace facility for use mainly when debugging
> \.{.bst} files.
>
> @d debug == @{          { remove the `|@{|' when debugging }
> @d gubed == @t@>@}      { remove the `|@}|' when debugging }
> @f debug == begin
> @f gubed == end
> @#
> @d stat == @{           { remove the `|@{|' when keeping statistics }
> @d tats == @t@>@}       { remove the `|@}|' when keeping statistics }
> @f stat == begin
> @f tats == end
> @#
> @d trace == @{          { remove the `|@{|' when in |trace| mode }
> @d ecart == @t@>@}      { remove the `|@}|' when in |trace| mode }
> @f trace == begin
> @f ecart == end
> ```

Comment: As I implied in [a comment I made above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422242/bibtex-debugger#comment1055825_422242), this still seems rather heavy-handed, but it may have to do.