# How to run CXTeX?

Tags: plain-tex, build-system, web

In the spirit of questions [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84012/about-web2c-c-code-conversion), I'm trying to build a C version of *TeX-the-program*; specifically Taco's [CXTeX](http://metatex.org/cxtex/) (part of [MetaTeX](http://metatex.org/)).

On Ubuntu 14 I can get it to compile, which results in a binary executable called `cpdfetex`. If you run it (`./cpedetex`), you get the welcome message

> This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.11b-2.1 (Web2C 7.5.2, C port 0.5.1)

However, if you try to do anything past that (like compile a `.tex` file as `./cpdfetex foo.tex`, or type `\end` into the terminal), you get the error message

> I can't find the format file `cpdfetex.efm'!

Any idea what to do?

(What's an `.efm` file supposed to contain, in the first place?)

---

*Edit*. The **motivation** is three-fold. I want a TeX distribution that is
**1)** barebones (just Knuth's plain TeX + Metafont), **2)** fast (for a small file, I get `4ms` compile times with KerTeX, `20ms` with TeX Live's TeX, `30ms` with eTeX`, 40ms` with pdfTeX, `120ms` with LuaTex on `dvi` mode), and **3)** hackable (preferably C-based, but at this point I'll take anything that compiles and runs...).

In particular, I want to access the final raw stream of bytes containing the `.dvi` output (right before it's written to disk) and pass it to a C program I'm writing (which understands the `.dvi` format). I'm currently writing the `.dvi` output to disk (using TeX-the-program) and reading it from disk (with the other program), but it'd be nicer to keep it all in memory.

Comment: Yes you need to generate/dump format files. I ran into this too, I've forgotten the exact details.

Comment: Thanks! What's a format file? A format file for _what_? What programs generates/dumps format files?

Comment: Wild guess: can you try `mktexfmt cpdfetex.efm` and see if it works? (I really don't know why a typical TeX distribution is made so hard to build…) (BTW I recently wrote [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384871/why-doesnt-tex-have-a-proper-debugger/384881#384881) that referred to the same question as you refer to; in particular the posts of Graham Douglas may help: http://www.readytext.co.uk/?cat=8 (or other categories on his blog).)

Comment: How were you able to get it to compile BTW? I'm trying it out now (Ubuntu 17.04, gcc 6.3.3) and it fails with a compilation error.

Comment: Yeah I had to do a bit of hacking. Off the top of my head: 1) install `gcc-3.3` (from the Ubuntu repos) and force the Makefiles to use this version (add the line `CC = gcc-3.3` to some of the Makefiles), 2) remove references to `.exe` files from some Makefile (don't remember which), 3) remove the redefinition of the `libc` function `strndup()` from `perlemu.c` and `perlemu.h` (I think that's what the files called)

Comment: The Graham Douglas posts are _super_ useful. In particular, they explain what a __format file__ (`.efm`) is. (Short answer: a format file `.efm` is a __binary brain-dump__.)
Also, when I run `mktexfmt cpdfetex.efm` I get the error `fmtutil: unknown format type: cpdfetex.efm.` =(

Comment: Yes I was able to compile it as well, with the same changes (2) and (3) except that instead of (1) using gcc-3.3 I renamed the variable `cs_count` in `cpdfetex/pdftex/writet1.c`. And now I'm stuck in the same way as you :-) BTW, Graham Douglas mentions he did build and get CxTeX working at some point, in [these](http://www.readytext.co.uk/?p=2475) [two](http://www.readytext.co.uk/?p=3115) posts. So it's definitely possible, I just don't understand enough. But trying to build LuaTeX may be an easier alternative today.

Comment: Phew, it's great to know that you got it to compile, too! At least now we're in the same boat =D Also, your solution to the GCC problem is awesome

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but just FYI: Your question reminded me: I just asked (and answered) a question about another TeX implementation, NTS written in Java, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385645/is-nts-new-typesetting-system-the-java-implementation-of-tex-usable-today). I don't know your specific motivation for trying CXTeX, but some of it may be addressed by either NTS or LuaTeX (or one of the other TeX implementations that actually exist!)

Comment: Well I managed to dump a format file after copying `plain.tex`, `hyphen.tex`, and all the relevant `*.tfm` files (`cm*.tfm` and also `manfnt.tfm`) into the current folder, and then running `cpdfetex -ini plain '\dump'`. It appears to dump the format successfully, but when I try to use it: `cpdfetex -debug-format -efm=plain hello.tex` it fails with `Fatal format file error(); I'm stymied`. It appears that for some reason the undumping code isn't an exact inverse of the dumping code, so it's not able to read from `plain.efm` correctly.

Comment: Sigh it's because `dump_int` uses `integer` (8 bytes), while `undump_int` uses `int` (4 bytes). I think CXTeX basically assumes int=integer=8 bytes (I guess), in which case I imagine needing extensive changes to the code.

Comment: OMG I changed `types.h` from `typedef long int integer` to `typedef int integer`, and it actually works! At least for simple things like `story.tex` — running on `gentle.tex` failed on page 4, with `This can't happen (mlist4)`. But those can be debugged probably, and I think typesetting simple files (I tried a few) is already awesome. Will post an answer later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly: LuaTeX is a descendant of CXTeX. Why do I say this? I cannot read Dutch, but I notice certain similarities between these two papers both by Taco Hoekwater: [*De CXTeX distributie*](http://www.metatex.org/docs/maps30-paper.pdf) (MAPS 30, Voorjar (Spring) 2004) and [*LuaTEX says goodbye to
Pascal*](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96hoekwater-pascal.pdf) (MAPS 39, EuroTeX 2009). :-) So when the latter paper says:

> In the winter of 2008–2009, we invested a lot of time in hand-converting the entire LuaTeX code base into a set of C source files that are much closer to current programming practices. The big WEB file has been split into about five dozen pairs of C source files and include headers.

I imagine that this effort was influenced / helped by the author's earlier experience with CXTeX. So you may want to just use LuaTeX (which too is written in C). It has had more development and testing, and is known to work.

---

Here's how I was able to get CXTeX to work, somewhat (at least for non-math), using the “data” files from a TeX Live distribution. (Ubuntu 17.04, gcc 6.3.3.)

1. Create a directory for cxtex, get sources, unpack them:

   ```
   mkdir cxtex && cd cxtex
   wget http://metatex.org/cxtex/cxtex-source-0.51.tar.gz
   tar xvfz cxtex-source-0.51.tar.gz
   cd cxtex-0.51/
   ```
2. In `cpdfetex/pdftex/writet1.c`, globally rename `cs_count` to some other name (I used `cs_count_here`). Reason: There's a conflict between

   ```
   EXTERN int cs_count; /* total number of known identifiers */
   ```

   on line 29 of `cpdfetex/hash.h`, and `cpdfetex/pdftex/writet1.c` which has

   ```
   static int cs_count, cs_size, cs_size_pos;
   ```

   on line 238, besides other mentions of `cs_count`.
3. In `texutil/perlemu.h` and `texutil/perlemu.c` and `texutil/texexec.c`, globally rename `strndup` to some other name consistently (I used `strndup_here`). Reason: there's a standard function called `strndup` in libc. (Note: You may also be able to just get rid of the definition in `strndup` in the files `texutil/perlemu.{h,c}`, so that that `texutil/texexec.c` uses the standard libc function. It will probably work, but I haven't tried this.)
4. Edit `cpdfetex/types.h` to change

   ```
   typedef long int integer;
   ```

   to

   ```
   typedef int integer;
   ```

   Reason: When dumping format files, the function `dump_int` uses type `integer`, while `undump_int` seems to be often called with something of type `int`. When I was compiling it, for my combination of compiler and machine architecture, we had `integer` being 8 bytes and `int` being 4 bytes, which is incompatible. There may be other and better solutions to this problem, but this is what I did.
5. In `Makefile` (the top-level one, inside `cxtex/cxtex-0.51`), remove the mentions of the `.exe` files: change

   ```
   all:
       cd texk/kpathsea && $(MAKE)
       cd cpdfetex && $(MAKE)         && cp cpdfetex.exe cpdfetex ../built
       cd texutil  && $(MAKE) texutil && cp texutil.exe  texutil  ../built
       cd texutil  && $(MAKE) texexec && cp texexec.exe  texexec  ../built
   ```

   to

   ```
   all:
       cd texk/kpathsea && $(MAKE)
       cd cpdfetex && $(MAKE)         && cp cpdfetex ../built
       cd texutil  && $(MAKE) texutil && cp texutil  ../built
       cd texutil  && $(MAKE) texexec && cp texexec  ../built
   ```

   Reason: We aren't building on Windows, so there won't be any `.exe` files.

With these changes, we are ready to compile:

```
make
```

Note that there are lots of warnings, including warnings of undefined behaviour and array out-of-bounds accesses. This indicates the codebase isn't quite perfect. When `make` is done, three binaries are created in `built/`: `cpdfetex`,  `texexec`, and `texutil`. There's still some work before they can be used.

1. Move to a particular directory: I just went up one level, to my `cxtex` directory:

   ```
   cd ..
   ```
2. Create a pdftex.cfg file:

   ```
   touch pdftex.cfg
   ```
3. Copy `plain.tex`:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex .
   ```
4. Copy all the files it references (fonts and hyphenation):

   ```
   cp /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/{cmr{10,9,8,7,6,5},cmmi{10,9,8,7,6,5},cmsy{10,9,8,7,6,5},cmex10,cmss10,cmssq8,cmssi10,cmssqi8,cmbx{10,9,8,7,6,5},cmtt{10,9,8},cmsltt10,cmsl{10,9,8},cmti{10,9,8,7},cmu10,cmmib10,cmbsy10,cmcsc10,cmssbx10,cmdunh10}.tfm .
   cp /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/knuth-lib/manfnt.tfm .
   cp /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex .
   ```
5. Dump format file:

   ```
   ./cxtex-0.51/built/cpdfetex -ini plain.tex '\dump'
   ```

This creates a file called `plain.efm`. And now cxtex is usable!

Create a test file:

```
    echo "hello \bye" > hello.tex
```

and run it through TeX!

```
    ./cxtex-0.51/built/cpdfetex -efm=plain hello.tex
```

I've tried this with a few example plain-TeX files like "story.tex" and even "xii.tex", it works. But when I tried [`gentle.tex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gentle), it only got through four pages (one of them happens to be an empty page) before failing with:

```
! This can't happen (mlist4).
\Big ...eft #1\vbox to11.5\p@ {}\right .\n@space $
                                                  }}
l.477 \line{4.~$\Bigl\{
                       $Groups, $\bigl\{$Groups, $\{$and More%
```

So there are some bugs in the code (possibly ones we introduced with our changes), that still need to be debugged. Happy hacking!

The cool thing is that ([unlike NTS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385645/is-nts-new-typesetting-system-the-java-implementation-of-tex-usable-today/)) even LaTeX can work:

1. Copy these files from the TeX Live sources: `texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/*` and `texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/latex-fonts/*.tfm`.
2. Run

   ```
   ./cxtex-0.51/built/cpdfetex -ini
   ```

   and at the `**` prompt type `*` and Enter, then

   ```
   \input latex.ltx
   ```

   This dumps the format to file `texput.efm` (couldn't figure out how to change that), which if you which you can rename to `latex.efm`.

Then with a file `test.tex` like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

This is a document.

Hello world.

This is math $x$ and $y$.

This is also math:

$$z$$

\end{document}
```

you can run:

```
./cxtex-0.51/built/cpdfetex -efm=texput test.tex
```

(or `efm=latex` if you renamed it).

The moment there is anything nontrivial in math mode (anything more than a single letter or digit), it seems to be buggy and either crash or give weird errors. Now that the source code to your TeX program is readable C, you can have fun debugging those. :-)

Comment: What an answer! Thanks so much! Sadly, when I try to run `./cxtex-0.51/built/cpdfetex -efm=plain hello.tex`, I get the error: `(Fatal format file error(); I'm stymied)`. But this approach looks promising, since I finally know explicitly how to generate an `.efm` file, and what it should contain.

Comment: @étale-cohomology I was getting exactly that error before I made the `typedef int integer` change. Note that you can pass `-debug-format` which will tell a little bit more.

Comment: Yes, that fixed that error! The command `cxtex-0.51/built/cpdfetex -ini plain.tex '\dump'` generates `No pages of output`, but it does output a `plain.efm` file (size: `227k`). (However, `pdftex.cfg` is still `0k` in size, which makes we wonder what purpose it serves!) Now, when I run `cxtex-0.51/built/cpdfetex -efm=plain hello.tex`, I get the error: `This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.11b-2.1 (Web2C 7.5.2, C port 0.5.1 
 (./hello.tex{pdftex.cfg}Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Also, in case you're curious, I edited in some motivation in the OP =)

Comment: Sorry to hear about the segmentation fault; guess the two versions of the compiler generated different code for the undefined behaviour. I guess you can work through it in a debugger… let me know if you fix it!

Comment: Will do! But is `pdftex.cfg` supposed to remain empty? Why do we create it in the first place?

Comment: @étale-cohomology As I understand it, it's a config file that the program expects: it fails if the file isn't there, but it's ok for the file to be empty. Searching through the code, it appears to be read in `cxtex-0.51/cpdfetex/pdftex/config.c` function `readconfigfile`, and can contain options like `page_height`, `output_format`, `pdf_minorversion` and the like.